# Why won't my If statement with multiple -AND conditions function correctly?

Tags: powershell

I am wanting to meet multiple conditions in my Powershell If statement and am trying to use the -AND operator to achieve it, but it seems to be just jumping straight to the else clause.

In the code below I want to make sure both folders have no files and that the "watcher.txt" file exists.

```
$Success = "C:\temp\Success"
$Failed = "C:\temp\failed"
$watcher = "C:\temp\watcher.txt"

$directoryInfo3 = get-childitem "$Success\\*" -file | Measure-Object
$directoryInfo3.count
$directoryInfo4 = get-childitem "$Failed\\*" -file | Measure-Object
$directoryInfo4.count
    if ((test-path -path $Watcher) -AND 
        ($directoryInfo3 -eq 0) -AND 
        ($directoryInfo4 -eq 0)){
         Write-host "Success folder and Failed folder are empty, and Watcher file exists."}
         else
         {Write-host "Not complete yet, rechecking folders."}
```

If all three statements are true, then I should see "Success folder and Failed folder are empty, and Watcher file exists."

Instead I am seeing "Not complete yet, rechecking folders." no matter what the condition is, even if all three are true.

Comment: Are you sure that the second and third condition is true? Did you try three and conditions where you definitely know that every condition is true? Your AND conditions look good but probably your conditions do not equal true.

Comment: Yes definitely all True. I just double checked spelling of files and folders and they are all correct. I made all conditions false to see what would happen, but still get the same outcome. I recreated the folders as well in case there were any hidden files, but still no luck.

Comment: For the future, just check each statement like this: `($directoryInfo3 -eq 0)` - this would show you `False`.

Comment: You're spot on. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to call `$directoryInfo3.count` for the statement to result in true. 
i.e.:

```
PS C:\> $dir = gci c:\temp\ -file | measure
PS C:\> $dir


Count    : 36
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :

PS C:\> $dir -eq 36
False
PS C:\> $dir.count -eq 36
True
```

Comment: Bloody perfect! I facepalmed myself pretty hard, I should've seen that. Thanks a million!

Comment: No worries, I'm guilty of this far too often!

Answer (score 1):

As you don't seem to be interested in the count or content of the `Get-ChildItem`,
you could use `Test-Path` for all 3 conditions

```
## Q:\Test\2019\05\30\SO_56373080.ps1
$Success =  "C:\temp\Success"       
$Failed  =  "C:\temp\failed"       
$watcher =  "C:\temp\watcher.txt"  

if ( (Test-Path -Path $Watcher   -PathType Leaf) -AND 
    !(Test-Path -Path $Success\* -PathType Leaf) -AND 
    !(Test-Path -Path $Failed\*  -PathType Leaf)){
    Write-host "Success folder and Failed folder are empty, and Watcher file exists."
} else {
    Write-host "Not complete yet, rechecking folders."
}
```

Here `!` = Not inverses the boolean result.

Comment: This is also a great solution and is actually cleaner for the purpose I need it for. I hadn't seen the "Leaf" parameter before, that's handy! Thanks